# java mouselistener difference windows xp and mac os

Tags: java, windows, macos, swing, listener

I'm implementing a Java Swing GUI which has a couple of JLabels, who are displayed a few times on a JFrame. For this reason I instanced the labels and stored them in a Vector. For each of the labels I added a listener like this in the constructor of my JFrame extending class:

```
b1.addMouseListener(new LabelMouseListener(...));
```

Every time I want to display the labels, I pick them from the vector and add them as a component on the frame. This works fine. And also, the listener, I added in the constructor is listening. But, there is a difference between the behavior on a Mac and on a PC. On a Mac it works completely fine, but on a PC (Win XP) I need to click the label twice before the listener reacts.
The LabelMouseListener implements MouseListener and I override the mouseClicked method. Maybe it also depends on the JavaRE, because on the Mac I use the 1.6, on the Win, I use 1.7. Is this a known problem, or do you have any suggestions for the cause of the error?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Windows XP - are you sure you aren't moving your mouse during the press+release - this prevents a mouse clicked event? Typically it is better to use mousePressed or mouseReleased instead of mouseClicked because of that.
Also see the MouseEvent#isPopupTrigger() javadoc for platform differences

Comment: It might have to do something with the logic coded in your event handler. I never saw this platform specific difference.

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I think i fell into a common pithole. I didn't started a new Thread inside the listener, so the listener was waiting until the old one was ready before the event could been fired again. And because the mac was a slightly faster machine, the error was overseen.